# auto refresh of combobox in java

Tags: java, swing, combobox, jframe

hello everyone just need a bit of help here:

```
            JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
        comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"Select", "Single", "Twin", "Double", "Suit", "Conference"}));


        String[] single = d.getAvaSinglelist().toArray(new String[d.getAvaSinglelist().size()]);
        String[] Dbroon = d.getAvaDoublelist().toArray(new String[d.getAvaDoublelist().size()]);
        String[] Twin = d.getAvaTwinlist().toArray(new String[d.getAvaTwinlist().size()]);
        String[] Suit = d.getAvaSuitslist().toArray(new String[d.getAvaSuitslist().size()]);
        String[] conf = d.getAvaConferencelist().toArray(new String[d.getAvaConferencelist().size()]);
        JComboBox comboBox_1 = new JComboBox();

            if(comboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Single")){
                comboBox_1.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(single));
            }

            if(comboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Twin")){
                comboBox_1.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(Dbroon));
            }
            if(comboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Double")){
                comboBox_1.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(Twin));
            }
            if(comboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Suit")){
                comboBox_1.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(Suit));
            }
            if(comboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Conference")){
                comboBox_1.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(conf));
            }
```

so what i want to do and cant find out how is to refresh the second combobox based on the selected item of the first one in a dynamic mode but as you guys can see also i have no idea 
every tip is welcome

Comment: *"every tip is welcome"*  When posting to SO.  Use your caps. key at the start of sentences.  Leave off noise like 'thanks' at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an `ActionListener` to your first `JComboBox`. Then add the logic for updating the second combo box inside that code.

Comment: Cannot refer to a non-final variable comboBox inside an inner class defined in a different method.      
that is the error im getting any help ??

Comment: You can make the JComboBox variables final if you only set them once.